# What is the easiest way to load a clojure library all the time?

Tags: clojure

A question from an utter newcomer to clojure:  What if I want to be able to start a clojure REPL from anywhere, for example because I just want to compute an exponent?  How can I set up my system to do this?  (I've deleted earlier links to not-quite-answers because they were cluttering up the question.) The Pomegranate documentation linked by @Jared314's answer below helped me see that I can do this:

```
~$ lein repl
...
user=> (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
nil
user=> (add-dependencies :coordinates '[[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]])
{[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"] nil, [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"] #{[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]}}
user=> (use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)
nil
user=> (expt 2 3)
8
```

Yay!

Now how can I make this happen every time I start the REPL, no matter what subdirectory I'm in?

I think I'm just ignorant of basic clojure setup.  Sorry about that.

Second major edit:

I've figured out that if I use raw clojure without lein, I can execute commands on startup of the repl.  For example, if the file `.clojurerc` contains the text `(print "Yow!\n")`, I can do this:

```
~$ java -cp /usr/local/lib/clojure-1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main -i .clojurerc -r
Clojure 1.5.1
Yow!
user=>
```

Can I do something like this with `lein`?  Or maybe better yet, load clojure.math.numeric-tower automatically in clojure without using lein (since for simple command line experimentation, lein's startup is slower than starting clojure directly).

(It may seem as if I'm not trying to solve this on my own, but I that's not so.  I have been doing web searches and experimenting, but I keep hitting brick walls. I'm starting to feel as if clojure is *only* intended for full-blown programming projects.  I had assumed that it could be good for add-hoc experiments and calculations (as lisps traditionally are but Java is not).  I'm not trying to incite arguments.  I'm just frustrated.  There ought to be a simple, well-known formula for doing what I'm trying to do.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want external dependencies you will need either a new project, `lein new testproject1`, the [lein-oneoff plugin](https://github.com/mtyaka/lein-oneoff), [Pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate), a Leiningen profile `:dependencies` entry, or some specific IDE feature. (I know at least LightTable allows external dependencies in their Instarepl, so I assume you can do it in Emacs and CCW.)

It might be best to start with creating a new test project so you can see the `project.clj` layout. But, if you just want a one-off library in a repl, take a look at the [instructions](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate#add-classpath-usage) for Pomegranate's `add-classpath` command. Pomegranate is accessible by default in the `lein repl`, so their example should work without anything extra.

**Edit:**

From your updated question, it sounds like you want a persistent repl dependency. You can add `[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]` to your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` profile file, under the `:repl` profile.

```
{:user {}
 :repl {:dependencies [[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]]
        :repl-options {:init (use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)}}}
```

Then when you run `lein repl`:

```
(expt 2 3) ;=> 8
```

Comment: Thanks Jared314.  Up until the point when you provided the very helpful link to that bit of Pomegranate documentation, I think I was already able to do everything you suggested.  Have edited question to exhibit what remains as a puzzle.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. I didn't completely understand your original question. I've updated my answer with info on the lein profiles configuration.

Comment: Thanks Jared314.  Perfect.  Now how can I get the effect of running `(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)` automatically, so that I can just enter `(expt 2 3)` immediately after I start the repl?  Adding `(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)` in profile.clj is ignored, even with various experiments using `unquote` or `~`, seemingly suggested by [sampleproject.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj).

Comment: I've updated the configuration to `use` the library on init. The syntax in [sample.project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L296) is correct, but the placement is slightly different in a profile.clj configuration.

Comment: My faith in clojure is restored :-) , and I can see that once I get used to some basic lein-voodoo, the config files will be very useful (and probably easier than the Java voodoo it they cover up).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this question a few months later, I realized that I settled on a different solution, but never posted it.  I now leave references to `math.numeric-tower` out of both .clojurerc and .lein/project.clj, since I don't need it for most Leiningen projects.  And when I want to use Clojure for quick calculations, I start Clojure via a shell script without Leiningen to avoid slow startup.  This is what's in the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

jars=/usr/local/lib/clojure-1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/usr/local/lib/clojure-1.5.1/math.numeric-tower-0.0.2.jar

while [ "$1" != "${1%.jar}" ]; do  # while param is a jar file
    jars="$jars:$1"
    shift
done
jars="$jars:."

exec rlwrap java -cp "$jars" clojure.main -e "(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)" "$@" -r
```

The middle part allows you to add jars on the command line, but in practice I don't find that useful, given that I use Leiningen for ongoing projects.  Someone else might find that part of the script useful, though.  rlwrap is a utility that gives you command line history, though it's not as good as what Leiningen provides, for my purposes.